# Вопрос по поводу деплоинга telegram bot'a написанного на Python на платформу heroku

Tags: python, telebot, heroku, deploy

У меня есть музыкальный telegram бот, который отправляет мне музыку по нажатию кнопок, музыка предварительно загружена на мой пк, также в боте реализован механизм добавление новой музыки по названию, опять же на мой пк. И у меня возникает вопрос, как такого бота правильно задеплоить на heroku? Во всех руководствах и видео, которые мне удалось найти, показывается, как залить обычного(простейшего) бота, который никак не взаимодействует с файлами компьютера, но для моего
бота такой механизм, как мне кажется, не подойдёт.

Comment: Ну это вам на свой пк надо деплоить бота тогда.

Comment: Не совсем понял.

Comment: В смысле чтобы иметь доступ к вашим файлам бот должен работать на вашем пк. Ну или придётся ещё одно звено колхозить для заливки и скачивания файлов на пк

Comment: А как тогда реализуются боты, где отправленные файлы заранее загружены куда-то, и они просто по ним шерстят  ?

Comment: Нет, ну так то варианты есть. Можно разными способами файлы пошарить: www, ftp, файловая шара. Просто вам придётся лишние промежуточные звенья делать - учить бота заливать/скачивать файлы и поддерживать у себя на компе этот сервис раздачи файлов.

Comment: А есть ли руководства по созданию и деплоингу бота, которые используют перечисленные вами методы, чтобы можно было разобраться в вопросе, а то держать постоянно включённым пк, явно не самая лучшая затея

Comment: Затея, которая ещё хуже - хранить данные у себя на ПК, которые можно залить на удалённый сервер или на сервер бота, чтобы не запариваться